# Uploading file to GoogleDrive causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am working on an android app and I am trying to integrate Google Drive into my app. The program is to allow syncing so it creates a file on the SD Card, and this file is then uploaded onto Google Drive. I am successfully authenticating but when I upload using the `insert` function I get an NullPointerException and I cannot see where the value is null as when I have stepped through everything nothing appears to be null.

Below is the code I am using to perform the upload.

```
private void uploadToDrive()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);

                    GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, DriveScopes.DRIVE);

                    credential.setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString("google_drive_account_name", ""));
                    Drive service = getDriveService(credential);

                    String storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(storageDir + "/folder/drive_sync.xml"));
                    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
                    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/xml", fileContent);

                    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
                    body.setTitle("My App Title");
                    body.setMimeType("text/xml");

                    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
                    if (file == null)
                    {
                        Log.e("UploadFile", "File was empty after insert");
                    }
                }
                catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e)
                {
                    activity.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), SynchronisationSettings.REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Log.d("Upload Drive", ex.toString());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.d("Upload File", ex.toString());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

Below is how I am getting the drive service

private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential)
{
    return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
}

And below is the stack trace that is outputted from the Exception

```
> 03-23 17:05:00.050: W/System.err(21664):
> java.lang.NullPointerException 03-23 17:05:00.055:
> W/System.err(21664):  at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:353) 03-23
> 17:05:00.055: W/System.err(21664):    at
> java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:204) 03-23 17:05:00.060:
> W/System.err(21664):  at
> com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.<init>(GenericUrl.java:100)
> 03-23 17:05:00.065: W/System.err(21664):  at
> com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:269)
> 03-23 17:05:00.065: W/System.err(21664):  at
> com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:408)
> 03-23 17:05:00.065: W/System.err(21664):  at
> com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:328)
> 03-23 17:05:00.070: W/System.err(21664):  at
> com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:449)
> 03-23 17:05:00.070: W/System.err(21664):  at
> com.BoardiesITSolutions.PasswordManager.Classes.DriveSync$1.run(DriveSync.java:85)
> 03-23 17:05:00.070: W/System.err(21664):  at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: What is at line 85 of DriveSync class?

Comment: @DamianJeżewski Line 85 is ``com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();``. I'm not sure which is null though as body and mediaContent doesn't appear to be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason, it was because I was using a different development PC and forgot to add the SHA1 fingerprint and add to the developer APIs console for the Drive API.

Comment: Do you have a link on how to do this?

Comment: Sorry no, I don't use this app any more so can't really remember. I think it was from the Google API Dashboard but can't remember for sure